# WooCommerce Custom Checkbox Checked by default

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to 'check' a checkbox by default in the WooCommerce checkout page.
I'm using the official WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor plugin to add a checkbox but it doesn't give me the ability to have the checkbox 'checked' by default.

I've tried using this code but it's not working:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields ( $fields ) {
    $fields['additional']['uncheck-to-opt-out-of-our-quarterly-newsletter-neuroscience-matters_field']['default'] = 1;
    return $fields;
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add checkbox on checkout page using below code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Add checkbox field to the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    $checked = $checkout->get_value( 'my_checkbox1' ) ? $checkout->get_value( 'my_checkbox1' ) : 1;

    echo '<div id="my-new-field"><h3>'.__('My Checkbox: ').'</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_checkbox1', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'         => __('I have read and agreed.'),
        'required'  => true,
        ), $checked);

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Adding custom fields [using `woocommerce_checkout_fields`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-6) is preferred over  [using `woocommerce_after_order_notes`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-7) unless one would like to fully control the rendering and validation. Also note to properly save and display such custom field several other hooks may need to be set up, like `woocommerce_checkout_process`, `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` etc.

Answer (score 2):

To define the default value of a custom WooCommerce field set up using the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook, it's best to hook another filter function to `woocommerce_checkout_get_value` or `default_checkout_<your_field_name>` hooks.

### `woocommerce_checkout_get_value`:

This one is a short circuit filter, which means if you use this, the `$value` will always start from `null` and if the returned `$value` is not `null` it prevents any attempt to read user's metadata for any previously defined user preferences.

In a sense it is kind of a hard default: for each checkout it uses the value defined in this filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'custom_override_checkout_get_value', 10, 2 );

public function custom_override_checkout_get_value( $value, $field ) {
    // $value is null or the result of previous filters
    if ( 'uncheck-to-opt-out-of-our-quarterly-newsletter-neuroscience-matters_field' === $field ) {
        $value = 1;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

### `default_checkout_<your_field_name>`:

This behaves similar to the one above, however this is called after the default value is read from a logged in user's defaults, which may have been set previously as metadata for the given user (e.g. saved during the last checkout if the user has already made a purchase before).

This can be considered a soft default, as with appropriate checks (like below: only set `$value` if `null`), the default is only applied if there is no existing user preference.

Also since this uses a dedicated hook name defined by the field name, there's no need to check which field the function is being called for.

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_uncheck-to-opt-out-of-our-quarterly-newsletter-neuroscience-matters_field', 'custom_override_default_checkout_field' );

public function custom_override_checkout_get_value( $value ) {
    // $value is read from logged in user's meta or null or the result of previous filters
    if ( is_null($value) ) {
        // Only use default if null, aka. if user has no previous preference saved.
        $value = 1;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

For more context check out `WC_Checkout::get_value()` method in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php` which calls both of these filters.