# WooCommerce radio option checked by default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button

[Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594628/10391705) for checkbox but I cannot find it for radio button.

For example I have 2 options radio and I want to make checked the first option by default.

```
'type'  => 'radio',
'class' => array('box form-row-wide'),
'options' => array(
    'default'  => 'Default option',
    'other'    => 'Other option',
  ),
```

Where to add $checked so the first option (Default option) will be checked by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. Here is the answer.

```
'type'  => 'radio',
'class' => array('box form-row-wide'),
'options' => array(
'default1'  => 'Default option',
'other2'    => 'Other option',
),
'default' => 'default1' ,
```

So it is 'default' => 'option you want to be checked',